# Run time error in Android

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ConstraintLayout cl;
int i;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cl=(ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.cl);
    cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb1);
    i=0;
 new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
       @Override
        public void run() {
          cl.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1500);
            if(i==0)
              cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb1);
            else if(i==1)
                cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb2);
            else if(i==2)
                cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb3);
            else if(i==3)
                cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb4);
            else if(i==4)
                cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb5);
            else if(i==5)
                cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb6);
           i++;
           cl.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1500);
        }
    },0,3000);
}
```

}

**Error**:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0

```
                                                                        android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6902)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1087)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5246)
                                                                            at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:13573)
                                                                            at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13509)
                                                                            at android.view.View.invalidateDrawable(View.java:17693)
                                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:432)
                                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setVisible(Drawable.java:816)
                                                                            at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:18160)
                                                                            at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:18136)
                                                                            at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:18119)
                                                                            at com.anilkrishna.baahubali2.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:30)
                                                                            at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
                                                                            at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

My app is running, the first image is being displayed, is fading out and then the app stops. The problem is with the if else loop. I'm not able to figure it out!

Comment: You need to say what the error is. Besides the code, that's arguably the most important information to include.

Comment: Can you share error log?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: Yeah, I did now. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the code inside timer on UI thread,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            cl = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.cl);
            cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb1);
            i = 0;
            new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                            cl.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1500);
                if (i == 0)
                  cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb1);
                else if (i == 1)
                  cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb2);
                else if (i == 2)
                  cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb3);
                else if (i == 3)
                  cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb4);
                else if (i == 4)
                  cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb5);
                else if (i == 5)
                  cl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb6);
                i++;
                cl.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1500);
                  }
                });

              }
            }, 0, 3000);
          }
```

Comment: That worked! Can you please explain the runOnUIThread part?
Thanks!

Comment: Basically in android all view operations are done on UI Thread also known as Main Thread. If you try to operate on any view outside UI Thread, it will throw exception. Hence, android provides a method in every activity 'runOnUiThread'

Comment: But on doing so, the animate functions are not working and a message is being displayed in log saying
"Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."